# How to get standard Mac OS X icons to use in your app?

Tags: macos, cocoa, osx-yosemite

How do you get standard Mac OS X icons to use in your design / app?

By standard icons I mean toolbar icons from this screenshots:
[image]
[image]

Is there a location where those files are stored or any way to extract them from the Mac OS X app?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

see [+[NSImage imageNamed:(NSString)name]](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSImage_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSImage/imageNamed:) and the links in that for the different list of os defined images...

eg.

`NSImage * img = [NSImage imageNamed:NSImageNameFolder];`

toolbar images specifically are listed:
https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSImage_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/constant_group/Toolbar_Named_Images

Comment: Looks like a very short list. Standard Finder has much more icons that also suits my app. Is it possible to extract those somehow?

Answer (score 1):

Not all of those are standard. For the ones which are, you use `+[NSImage imageNamed:]` with one of the system-defined image name constants, such as `NSImageNameGoLeftTemplate` or `NSImageNameIconViewTemplate`.

Comment: If some are non-standard, how to get them to use in my app? Don't want to change default user experience with custom icons. Is there a way to find a path or extract them from the app?

Comment: @zelid if they aren't shared by the os, then you have to provide the artwork yourself... it is very questionable practice to "borrow" images that aren't shared by the OS, but there should be plenty provided in free icon libraries, but they may not be 100% the same.

Comment: If they're not standard, then they aren't part of the "default user experience", they're app-specific. You need to design and use your own. Even if you could extract them from an Apple app, they're copyrighted and you're not entitled to ship them as part of your own app.

Comment: @Ken Although OP says "extract" it seems clear to me that he just wants to draw the images in his app, not copy and ship his own version. "If they're not standard, then they aren't part of the "default user experience"", perhaps, but there is undeniably an ocean of OS images which are not named or accessible through an API.  The brief list of toolbar images is nice; Apple could do vastly more along those lines, which would help developers maintain the Apple look and feel in their own apps.  I don't see how there could be an argument against that, except that Apple would have to spend time...

Comment: @zeppenwolf: Maybe that's what he wants, but: a) there's no supported way to access those images, and b) even if there were, they could change or go away with any software update, which makes them unsuitable for use in his app. Shipping his own images or using the supported APIs are the only good choices. If he's unsatisfied with the standard images supplied by the APIs, he should file a bug with Apple.

Answer (score 1):

Other images/icons are available from `IconServices`:

```
/*
   Type of the predefined/generic icons. For example, the call:
      err = GetIconRef(kOnSystemDisk, kSystemIconsCreator, kHelpIcon, &iconRef);
   will retun in iconRef the IconRef for the standard help icon.
*/

/* Generic Finder icons */

public var kClipboardIcon: Int { get }
public var kClippingUnknownTypeIcon: Int { get }
public var kClippingPictureTypeIcon: Int { get }
public var kClippingTextTypeIcon: Int { get }
public var kClippingSoundTypeIcon: Int { get }
public var kDesktopIcon: Int { get }
public var kFinderIcon: Int { get }
public var kComputerIcon: Int { get }
public var kFontSuitcaseIcon: Int { get }
public var kFullTrashIcon: Int { get }
public var kGenericApplicationIcon: Int { get }
public var kGenericCDROMIcon: Int { get }
...
...
```

You can use NSWorkspace icon methods with the above constants:

```
NSWorkspace.shared.icon(forFileType: NSFileTypeForHFSTypeCode(UInt32(kGenericApplicationIcon)))
```